# How to enable HTTP request logging in ActiveMQ for tracking RESTful API requests?

Tags: jetty, activemq-classic

I am working with ActiveMQ 5.15.16 and using the [RESTful API](https://activemq.apache.org/rest) for message processing. I want to enable logging of incoming HTTP requests for the ActiveMQ RESTful API in order to track and analyze the requests. However, I am not sure how to achieve this.

I read through the documentation of how to [configure Jetty Request Logs](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#configuring-jetty-request-logs), but I wasn't able to find the right file in ActiveMQ where to write the according logging config.

Could someone please guide me on how to enable HTTP request logging in ActiveMQ for tracking RESTful API requests?

Comment: Jetty configuration is done in `conf/jetty.xml`. You should be able to create a new `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler` bean and add it into the list of handlers in the `Server` bean.

Comment: It's worth noting that there is no industry standard for REST-based messaging so by adopting the API in ActiveMQ "Classic" you're locking yourself in to that specific implementation. Generally speaking, it is recommended that folks use STOMP instead of REST since STOMP is a widely adopted industry standard protocol that is similar in design to HTTP and has nearly as much support across platforms and languages as HTTP. This allows you to avoid vendor lock-in. To be clear, I say this as a committer on the ActiveMQ project.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: @JustinBertram Thanks for the advice. I agree that a dedicated messaging protocol is preferable to REST. But there may be situations where a communication partner has rather limited capabilities and REST is the only option.
I added my ActiveMQ version in the question.

Comment: As noted, STOMP has very good support across as wide variety of platforms so I think there's a good chance there's a STOMP client implementation they could use - even (and perhaps _especially_) in environments with limited capabilities. STOMP, in many ways, is simpler than HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> create a new org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler bean and add it into the list of handlers in the Server bean

### jetty.xml

```xml
<bean id="requestLogHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler">
    <property name="requestLog">
        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.CustomRequestLog">
            <constructor-arg index="0">
                <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncRequestLogWriter">
                    <property name="append" value="true" />
                    <property name="filename" value="M:/logs/activemq/requests-yyyy_mm_dd.log" />
                    <property name="timeZone" value="CET" />
                    <property name="retainDays" value="10" />
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <!--constructor-arg index="1" value="#{T(org.eclipse.jetty.server.CustomRequestLog).EXTENDED_NCSA_FORMAT}" /-->
            <constructor-arg index="1" value="%{client}a - %u %{dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss ZZZ|CET}t &quot;%r&quot; %s %O &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot;" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="Server" depends-on="jettyPort" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="handler">
        <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
            <property name="handlers">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="contexts" />
                    <ref bean="securityHandler" />
                    <ref bean="requestLogHandler" />
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Note that in Jetty 9+ you would be better served by using `Server.setRequestLog(new CustomRequestLog())`.   The `RequestLogHandler` is for context specific logging, while `Server.setRequestLog()` is for all requests, even those that don't belong to the context.

Comment: the `timeZone` property is for the filename when it rolls the file.  The logging of timeZone in the file is controlled by your CustomRequestLog pattern  (see javadoc for details).

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. Logging via Jetty. Sounds like this is the approach you started. More than likely, you have a log4j2 configuration to sort out vs an ActiveMQ question for this scenario.
2. Use the logging broker plugin, which can log processing for all protocols through the broker: [Logging Broker Plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/logging-interceptor)